# Database structure for tags?

Tags: database-design

I posted a thread on Stack Overflow and one person pointed out that my database structure wasn't the best so now I'm here to ask how to do this in a good and proper way.

Currently I have one table called "users" and in the table I have a lot of userinfo. In "users" I have a column called "tags" were information inside the column look like "#dj #personal #coding" and things like that for every user. Is there any better way to store tags describing the user? I have one column called "tags" were the user have stored tags describing him/her and also a column called "interests" were tags are stored to remember what the user is looking for...

Basically, is there any better way to store these tags for each user?

Comment: There was a flurry of activity about this in 2009 on StackOverflow ([one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/how-do-you-recommend-implementing-tags-or-tagging), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551453/scaling-web-applications-and-tagging-digg-del-icio-us-stackoverflow), [three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597016/what-tag-schemas-are-the-most-efficient-effective),[four](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48475/database-design-for-tagging)). The most popular schemas were much like @a1ex07's below.

Answer (score 4):

It makes sense to store tags themselves in a separate table, and add a link table to implement many-to-many relationship between users and tags, for example

```
users (user_id (PK), name, [other user attributes]);
tags(tag_id(PK), tag_name, [other tag attributes]);
users_tags(user_id (FK to users) ,tag_id (FK to tags), PK(user_id,tag_id));
```

Depends on your needs, `users_tags` may have other attributes as well, for instance you might want to add datetime column to store when user added tag (surely, if it has any value to your application)